# :q to quit from less and man. Are there other colon-commands in Bash/Zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

To quit from `man` or `less`, we use `:q`, like in Vim. But where can I read about this command and probably other similar commands (maybe `:w`, for example) in Bash or Zsh documentation? `help q`, `help :q`, `help quit` return "Command not found".

Comment: I don't think `cat` has any interactive commands like that. Did you mean `less` or `more`?

Comment: I mean `less`, sorry.

Comment: None of `man`, `more` or `less` need `:q`. They are ignoring the `:` because it means nothing to them. They all terminate with a simple `q`. `man` even states this at the end of each page of output. Each program has its own repertoire of commands, which may be similar to other programs to aid usability: but there are no generic sub-commands as such.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, `less` doesn't ignore the colon, e.g. `:n` (next file) is a different command from `n` (next search match). It's just that all of `q  :q  Q  :Q  ZZ` (as shown by the help view) are bound to exiting the program (on my Debian anyway).

Comment: @ilkkachu Noted. I don't use `less` much. Some of the commands have fairly arbitrary mappings -- e.g. `:q` quits both `less` and `vi`, although `q` quits `less` but starts recording a macro in `vi`. (My `vi` runs `vim` with `vi` emulation, which can also be confusing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man` typically uses `less`, and you can read about the keyboard shortcuts supported there in `man less`. Many features in `less` are based on `vi`, hence the similarities. (`vi` also provides a read-only variant, `view`, which can be used instead of `less`.)

None of this is handled by your shell, which is why you won’t find relevant information in your shell’s documentation.

Comment: Worth noting that `:` enters the `ex` aka *command line* mode in `vi`. In several tools including GNU `screen` or `mutt` (in addition to `less`), `:` can be used to enter some form of command line interface. Within `vim` (a popular implementation of `vi`) and other implementations, `:help :` or `:h :` to get help about `:`, and `:h :q` or `:help :quit` to learn about the `q`/`quit` `ex` command (`:help :help`, `man -a man` to get started).

Comment: The `emacs` equivalent would be Meta-X. zsh's line editor supports both a emacs-like (after `bindkey -e` like in tcsh) and vi-like (after `bindkey -v`) editing mode which respectively do support Meta-X and `:`, though it's the same emacs-style command-line that is supported in both (where you can enter widget names), not `ex` commands, and in particular, there is no `q` nor `quit` widget by default (though you could always create one yourself with `q quit() exit; zle -N q; zle -N quit`).

Answer (score 1):

None of bash, zsh, or cat support `:q` as a quit command.  Commands that start with a `:` are technically `ex` like commands.

When you run applications, the applications themselves handle things like this.  It may look like man is doing it, but man automatically runs a pager (pick one by setting environment variable `PAGER`) which by default on most linux systems is `less`.  (Older systems used `more` .) You can get a list of keys with `man less` or by typing the <kbd>h</kbd> key when in the pager. (I think almost all support the h help key.)

Note that in `vi` commands activated with `:` are actually from the older `ex` command line oriented editor.  When vi ("visual") was created, the ex editor was embedded in it because it handles some advanced things that the keystroke driven vi could not do.

In turn, ex was somewhat based on the even older `ed`.  The `ex` and `vi` commands typically shared a binary, and now `ex` and `vim` share a binary (and probably vi too).  The `ed` editor is still available on many unix like systems.

Note that less actually supports using the exit keys and commands (and several other simple action sequences) from multiple editors, including not just ex but also vi and emacs.  Likely this is to make people with muscle memory happy.

Comment: Technically, bash and zsh have a :q quoting *modifier* as used in `$var:q` or `!!:q` (only the latter in bash) for instance, but that's completely unrelated.

Comment: Ya, even the usage context is different for the variable modifiers.

Comment: The `:` in zsh's line editor when in vi mode is related though (see my second comment to Stephen's answer).

Comment: I figured zsh might have some tricks.